# How do you update a row using multiple search parameters in android?

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

Suppose I have an android sqlite table as follows:

```
Students

courseID   name    enrolled   final_year
   1       Adam      yes         no
   2       Bob       yes         no
   2       Brian     no          yes
   5       Brian     no          yes
   6       Claire    yes         no
```

Now say I want to update the table as follows.

```
UPDATE Students 
SET enrolled='yes'
WHERE courseID=2 and final_year='yes;
```

What is the best way of doing this in android?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ContentValues updateContent = new ContentValues();
updateContent.put("enrolled" , "yes");
db.update("Students" , updateContents, "courseID = ? and final_year = ?" , new String[] {"2" , "yes"});
```

Comment: Perfect! Few sources go beyond one-condition queries. Thank you.